# NestJS Insert a Comment into a user blog post

Tags: postgresql, nestjs

I have an app where an user can create a list of Recipes and each Recipe can have multiple comments that many users can post.
This is what im trying to do:
I have a comments Enitity:

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
  BeforeUpdate,
  ManyToOne,
  JoinColumn,
  ManyToMany,
} from 'typeorm';
import { UserEntity } from 'src/user/models/user.entity';
import { RecipeEntity } from 'src/recipe/model/recipe-entry.entity';
import { User } from 'src/user/models/user.interface';

@Entity('comments_entry')
export class CommentsEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
  createdAt: Date;

  @Column({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
  updatedAt: Date;

  @BeforeUpdate()
  updateTimestamp() {
    this.updatedAt = new Date();
  }

  @ManyToOne(
    type => UserEntity,
    user => user.username,
  )
  author: UserEntity;

  @Column()
  recipe_id: number;

  @Column()
  author_id: number;

  @ManyToOne(
    type => RecipeEntity,
    recipe => recipe.comment,
  )
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'recipe_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  comment: RecipeEntity;
}
```

Linked to a Recipe entity:

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
  BeforeUpdate,
  ManyToOne,
  JoinColumn,
  OneToMany,
  JoinTable,
  ManyToMany,
} from 'typeorm';
import { UserEntity } from 'src/user/models/user.entity';
import { CommentsEntity } from 'src/comments/model/comments.entity';

@Entity('recipe_entry')
export class RecipeEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  title: string;

  @Column()
  slug: string;

  @Column('text', { array: true, nullable: true })
  ingr: string[];

  @Column({ default: '' })
  description: string;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  body: string;

  @Column({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
  createdAt: Date;

  @Column({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
  updatedAt: Date;

  @BeforeUpdate()
  updateTimestamp() {
    this.updatedAt = new Date();
  }

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  headerImage: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  publishedDate: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  isPublished: boolean;

  @Column()
  user_id: number;

  @ManyToOne(
    type => UserEntity,
    user => user.recipeEntries,
  )
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  author: UserEntity;

  @Column({ default: 0 })
  totalWeight: number;

  @Column('text', { array: true, default: '{}' })
  dietLabels: string[];

  @Column({ default: 0 })
  calorieQuantity: number;

  @Column({ default: 0 })
  proteinQuantity: number;

  @Column({ default: 0 })
  carbQuantity: number;

  @Column({ default: 0 })
  fatQuantity: number;

  @Column({ default: 0 })
  sugarQuantity: number;

  @Column('text', { array: true, nullable: true })
  likes: string[];

  @Column({ default: false, nullable: true })
  isLiked: boolean;

  @OneToMany(
    type => CommentsEntity,
    comments => comments.comment,
  )
  comment: CommentsEntity[];
}
```

Linked to an User entity:

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
  BeforeInsert,
  OneToMany,
} from 'typeorm';
import { UserRole } from './user.interface';
import { RecipeEntity } from 'src/recipe/model/recipe-entry.entity';
import { CommentsEntity } from 'src/comments/model/comments.entity';

@Entity()
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  username: string;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Column({ select: false })
  password: string;

  @Column({ type: 'enum', enum: UserRole, default: UserRole.USER })
  role: UserRole;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  profileImage: string;

  @Column({ default: false, nullable: true })
  favourite: boolean;

  @OneToMany(
    type => RecipeEntity,
    recipeEntity => recipeEntity.author,
  )
  recipeEntries: RecipeEntity[];

  @OneToMany(
    type => CommentsEntity,
    recipeEntryEntity => recipeEntryEntity.author,
  )
  commentEntries: CommentsEntity[];

  @BeforeInsert()
  emailToLowerCase() {
    this.email = this.email.toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

As an user i can post recipes. But im failing to add comments on specific recipes.
2 errors:

1. When i create a Recipe with some hardcoded comments, the users and recipe table gets filled but the comments_entry table is empty.
   And im failing to implement the method to add comments to a specific recipe.

Controller:

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  @Post('recipe/:id')
  createComment(
    @Param() params,
    @Body() comment: string,
    @Request() req,
  ): Observable<RecipeEntry> {
    const user = req.user;
    const id = params.id;
    return this.recipeService.createComment(user, id, comment);
  }
```

```
createComment(id: number, commentEntry: string): Observable<RecipeEntry> {
    return from(this.findOne(id)).pipe(
      switchMap((recipe: RecipeEntry) => {
        const newComment = recipe.comment.push(commentEntry);
        return this.recipeRepository.save(newComment);
      }),
    );
  }
```

Type 'Observable<DeepPartial[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
Property 'comment' is missing in type 'DeepPartial[]' but required in type 'RecipeEntry'.ts(2322)
recipe-entry.interface.ts(18, 3): 'comment' is declared here.

Any help?

Comment: Please describe more clear what your issue. Posts its RecipeEntry entity? Because in question you wrote Post, but entity named RecipeEntry. And you want to connect: Recipe can have a User and many comments, Comment can have a User and a Recipe, User can have many Recipes and many Comments. So when you create new Comment you need to map it with User and with Recipe?

Comment: I updated my question, hope it helps to understand now. Basically is what you said. An user can post many recipes, a recipe can have many comments many comments can be posted into a recipe by many users.

Answer (score 0):

Can't build working example but may be would helpful:

```
Redo your relations (I simplified entities for example, but you should use full:) ):
@Entity('comments_entry')
export class CommentsEntity {
  @Column()
  authorId: number;

  @ManyToOne(type => UserEntity, user => user.id)
  author: UserEntity;

  @ManyToOne(type => RecipeEntity, recipe => recipe.id)
  recipe: RecipeEntity;
}

  @Entity('recipe_entry')
  export class RecipeEntity {  

    @Column()
    authorId: number;

    @ManyToOne(type => UserEntity, user => user.id)
    author: UserEntity;
  
    @OneToMany(type => CommentsEntity, comment => comment.recipe)
    comments: CommentsEntity[];
  }


  @Entity('user_entry')
  export class UserEntity {  
    @OneToMany( type => RecipeEntity, recipe => recipe.author)
    recipes: RecipeEntity[];
  
    @OneToMany(type => CommentsEntity, comment => comment.author)
    comments: CommentsEntity[];
  }
```

RecipeDto something like:

```
RecipeDto: {
   authorId: number | string,
   comments: CommentDto[],
   ****other recipe data
}
```

create new Recipe:

```
createRecipe(recipeDto: RecipeDto): Observable<RecipeEntry> {
    const { comments, authorId } = recipeDto;

    if(comments) {
        const commentPromises = comments.map(async comment => {
            comment.authorId = authorId;
            return await this.commentRepository.save(comment);
          });
    
      recipeDto.comments = await Promise.all(commentPromises);    
          
        }
      return await this.recipeRepository.save(recipeDto);
    }
```

Comment: Try remove manually dist folder, sometimes it help. Other way, you can create git repository for reproduce issue, and I'll see, when I have time.

Comment: Sure!
https://github.com/FACorreiaa/RecipePlatformAPI
I made a workaround, by putting a comments: string[] inside recipes, but i will change it later or when you can help me. At least for now i can test the frontend design etc.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I tried but can't help you :(. Issue not hard, but for reproducing need a lot of time. Usually I try to build much more easier and use base entities/controllers/services for extends.

Comment: No problem, i'll just have a big recipe table. Its just a personal project anyway,

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are trying that:

```
One User --> Many Recipes  
One User --> Many Comments  
One Recipe --> Many Comments
```

Your entities seems right.

Normally a typeorm repository returns a promise and not an observable.
You need to convert it to an Observable.

And at the moment you are trying to store a comment in the recipeRepo. You should save the whole recipe. And before you have to save the comment in the comment repo (if you are not working with cascades).
Something like this:

```
createComment(id: number, commentEntry: string): Observable<RecipeEntry> {
    return from(this.findOne(id)).pipe(
      switchMap((recipe: RecipeEntry) => { 
      return from(this.commentRepository.save(newComment)).pipe(
          map(com: Comment) => {
             recipe.comment.push(com);
             return from(this.recipeRepository.save(recipe));
          }
      )
    );
  }
```

If you enable cascades, you can do this in only one call.

Comment: Allright :)
Message me when it works :)
Otherwise i can look at it again at the weekend or you can upload the repo somewhere and i will check it out.

Comment: Still didnt have time to test it out, but i will do for sure tomorrow and pm you!

Comment: Im having an weird error:
Type 'Observable<Observable<RecipeEntry & RecipeEntity>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<RecipeEntry>'.
  Property 'id' is missing in type 'Observable<RecipeEntry & RecipeEntity>' but required in type 'RecipeEntry'.

If you have time i made the comment with "Thomas may help", implementing your code on the recipe service. 
https://github.com/FACorreiaa/RecipePlatformAPI

Comment: This is because the from() is unecessary here, i opened a pull req, where i fix the interfaces and entites, you will need to fix the rest. More in the pull request